# How does deleting an edge modify the number of strongly connected components?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, edges

Deleting an edge between two verticles that are part of two separate strongly connected components does not modify the total number. But how does deleting an edge between two verticles that are part of the same strongly connected component affect the number? It should increase it by 1 but what if there are multiple paths between those two nodes? Or only a unique path which will be altered by the deletion exists?

Answer (score 0):

Removing a single edge between two vertices within a strongly connected component will not always increase the number of strongly connected components by 1. A strongly connected component is, by definition, a subgraph of a directed graph that is maximally strongly connected. Meaning there is a path between all of the vertices. Therefore, in a SCC with V vertices, each vertex should be able to reach V other vertices. It is V instead of V-1 because a vertex can reach itself. Therefore, a single vertex can be a strongly connected component. As shown in the graph below, vertices A, B, C, and D form a SCC. But when the edge from D to A is removed, A, B, C, and D all become separate strongly connected components. So the number increased from 1 to 4 SCCs.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1OxD.png)

On the other hand, removing an edge between two vertices within a strongly connected component can also increase the number of SCCs by 0. The graph below contains a singular SCC. Although it may appear as 2 separate SCCs, it is not because SCCs are maximal and must be separated by an articulation point. Therefore, this graph contains 1 SCC. However, removing the edge from E to B results in one singular SCC. Therefore, the total number decreased by 0, not 1.

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqYYE.png)